# In iOS does either NSURL or NSXML span a new thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xcode, nsurl

I have a program that progresses as follows.  I call a method called `getCharacteristics`.  This method connects to a remote server via a NSURL connection (all networking code done in another file) and when it receives a response it makes a method call back to the original class.  This original class then parses the data (xml) and stores its contents as a map.

The problem I'm having is that it appears that somewhere in this transaction another thread is being spawned off.

Here is sample code showing what I'm doing:

```
@property map

- (void) aMethod
{
    [[WebService getSingleton] callWebService: andReportBackTo: self]
    Print "Ready to Return"
    return map;
}
- (void) methodThatIsReportedBackToAfterWebServiceRecievesResponse
{
    //Parse data and store in map
    Print "Done Parsing"
}
```

The problem that I am running into is that map is being returned before it can be fully created.  Additionally, "Ready to Return" is being printed before "Done parsing" which suggests to me that there are multiple threads at work.  Am I right? If so, would a simple lock be the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection will execute in another thread if you tell it to execute asynchronously.

In my opinion the best way to deal with this would be to write your own delegate protocol, and use delegation to return your map when the you have downloaded and parsed your data.

You could retrieve your data synchronously using NSURLConnection, but you may force the user to wait for an extended period of time especially if a connection timeout occurs. I would avoid this approach.